# Creating JWT for Epic backend authentication

Tags: c#, jwt, rsa

I am attempting to connect to the Epic sandbox environment via a backend app.  I have been following this [guide](https://fhir.epic.com/Documentation?docId=oauth2&section=BackendOAuth2Guide) but I think I am running into an issue with my JWT signature.  Here is the code I am using to generate the token

```
class CreateJwt
{
    public static string? Token { get; set; }
    public static void Jwt()
    {

        try
        {
            
            // reading the content of a private key PEM file
            string privateKeyPem = File.ReadAllText("./private_epic_backend_key.pem");

            // keeping only the payload of the key 
            privateKeyPem = privateKeyPem.Replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
            privateKeyPem = privateKeyPem.Replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");

            byte[] privateKeyRaw = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKeyPem);

            // creating the RSA key 
            RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
            provider.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(privateKeyRaw), out _);
            RsaSecurityKey rsaSecurityKey = new RsaSecurityKey(provider);

            // Generating the token 
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

            var claims = new[] {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iss, "1a467f07-8a84-4e25-a493-4ba9d5ef9054"),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "1a467f07-8a84-4e25-a493-4ba9d5ef9054")
            };

            var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            var token = new JwtSecurityToken
            (
                "1a467f07-8a84-4e25-a493-4ba9d5ef9054",
                "https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/oauth2/token",
                claims,
                now.AddMilliseconds(-30),
                now.AddMinutes(4),
                new SigningCredentials(rsaSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha384)
            );

            // handler.WriteToken(token) returns the token ready to send
            Token = handler.WriteToken(token);
            Console.WriteLine(Token);

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(
                 new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().ToString()
            );
        }

    }
}
```

The reason I think the issue is with the signature is because when I load the token into JWT.IO I get an "invalid signature" response. Then here is the code where I am sending it.

```
class GetBearerToken
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    public static string? Bearer { get; set; }

public async static Task Authorize()
    {
        try
        {
            var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "grant_type", "client_credentials" },
                { "client_assertion_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer" },
                { "client_assertion", CreateJwt.Token }
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            var requeststring = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(requeststring);

            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/oauth2/token", content);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            Console.WriteLine("response from post");
            Console.WriteLine(responseString);
           
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(
                 new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().ToString()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

This looks exactly like what they are expecting according to the documentation Epic provides, but I am getting a return that states

"error": "invalid_client",
"error_description": null

Epic provides a [troubleshooting document](https://fhir.epic.com/Resources/jwt_auth_troubleshoot_eof) that goes over this particular error, but it seems to be more of a catchall error.  I have gone through the troubleshooting steps twice now and I am still not getting past this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: regarding the invalid signature on jwt.io: did you provide the public key on jwt.io (right column under VERIFY SIGNATURE)? Without the public key, the signature can't be verified.

Comment: I did add the public key in the verify signature section, I used the cert value that starts with "MIIDETCCA" and ends with "DyM7/4" but I was not sure what to add for the private key in that same section.  I tried a few different values and none of them change the invalid signature output.

Answer (score 1):

```
// This is the refactoring of these two classes that will work:
// env. .NET 7

using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace EPICAPI.AppTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _ = GetBearerToken.Authorize();
        }

        public class CreateJwt
        {
            public static string Jwt()
            {
                try
                {
                    // reading the content of a private key PEM file
                    string privateKeyPem = File.ReadAllText(@"L:\OpenSSL\keys\privatekey.pem");

                    // keeping only the payload of the key 
                    privateKeyPem = privateKeyPem.Replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", string.Empty);
                    privateKeyPem = privateKeyPem.Replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", string.Empty);
                    byte[] privateKeyRaw = Convert.FromBase64String(privateKeyPem);

                    // Generating the token 
                    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    
                    Guid gJti = Guid.NewGuid(); // you may improve it

                    IEnumerable<Claim> claims = new[] {
                       // new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iss, "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"), // do not use this in claims
                       new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"),
                       new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, gJti.ToString())
                    };

                    JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new();

                    // creating the RSA key 
                    RSACryptoServiceProvider provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                    provider.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(new ReadOnlySpan<byte>(privateKeyRaw), out _);

                    RsaSecurityKey rsaSecurityKey = new RsaSecurityKey(provider);

                    JwtSecurityToken jwtToken = new JwtSecurityToken
                    (
                        issuer: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                        audience: "https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/oauth2/token",
                        claims: claims,
                        notBefore: now.AddMilliseconds(-30),
                        expires: now.AddMinutes(4),
                        signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(rsaSecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha384)
                    );

                    string accessToken = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtToken);
                    Console.WriteLine(accessToken);

                    return accessToken;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().ToString());

                    return string.Empty;
                }
            }
        }

        public class GetBearerToken
        {
            public async static Task Authorize()
            {
                string token = CreateJwt.Jwt();

                try
                {
                    HttpClient client = new();
                    HttpRequestMessage request = new(HttpMethod.Post, "https://fhir.epic.com/interconnect-fhir-oauth/oauth2/token");

                    var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                    {
                        new("grant_type", "client_credentials"),
                        new("client_assertion_type", "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer"),
                        new("client_assertion", token)
                    };

                    FormUrlEncodedContent content = new(values);
                    request.Content = content;

                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.Send(request);

                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine(new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace().ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**